# How to avoid file conflicts between attempted installs during a BitBake build?

Tags: package, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I have two autotools-based BitBake recipes which both provide the same named file (and both install in usr/bin) which causes an error:

```
error: file /usr/bin/example conflicts between attempted installs of recipe1-0.1-r0.x86 and recipe2-0.1-r0.x86
```

I found that I can fix this problem but this really seems like a hackaround with really bad style. If you put this in one of the recipes which provides the example file, it will avoid this specific error, but can cause other errors.

```
do_install_append () {
    rm -f ${D}${bindir}/example
}
```

Is there a better way to avoid this conflict? I thought there might be some hope for `PREFERRED_PROVIDER` but haven't had any success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way of solving this is the update-alternatives class. See meta/classes/update-alternatives.bbclass and the Yocto Project Reference Manual entry on update-alternatives.bbclass. http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-classes-update-alternatives is the link to that.

Comment: what if the file is not a binary file?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the key question is why do both recipes install the same file, and what should happen if both packages are installed?  Just deleting the file is a perfectly good fix in the right situations, or use update-alternatives if you need to pick between the two files, or rename the files in do_install so they're not conflicting...