# Petalinux--ERROR:conflicts between attempted installs

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe, petalinux, inittab

I am trying to modify /etc/inittab file to add a restart function. To check whether I can add a line in inittab, I created a demo. I created a .bb file under proect-spec/meta-user/recipes-apps:

```
#
# This is the GPIO-DEMO apllication recipe
#
#

SUMMARY = "automatic-restart application"
SECTION = "PETALINUX/apps"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
SRC_URI = "file://* \
        "
S = "${WORKDIR}"
FILESEXTAPATHS_preprend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
#inherit update-rc.d

INITSCRIPT_NAME = "hello"
INITSCRIPT_PARAMS = "start 98 5 ."

do_install() {
        install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d
        install -m 0755 ${S}/hello ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d/hello
    install -d ${D}/opt/hello
    cp ${S}/hello.elf ${D}/opt/hello/

}

do_install_append(){

    echo "adding a line" >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/inittab

}

FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/*"
FILES_${PN} += "/opt/hello/"
```

By the way, this file is used firsly put an .elf file under /etc/init.d and it worked.
However, when I was adding these below code block to check whether I can modify "inittab" :

```
do_install_append(){
    echo "adding a line" >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/inittab

}
```

then building the petalinux project, I encountered with this error:
**"file /etc/inittab conflicts between attempted installs of hello-1.0-r0.cortexa9hf_neon and sysvinit-inittab-2.88dsf-r10.plnx_zynq7"**

Answer (score 0):

This is a well known issue in Yocto which is you cannot ship two packages(recipes) that are installing the same file in the final rootfs.

So, either you remove one of `hello` or `sysvinit-inittab` from the image, or use `update-alternatives` class as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179674/how-to-avoid-file-conflicts-between-attempted-installs-during-a-bitbake-build).